# Stuck on SQL server nested queries/cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I want it to display running percentage of each sum of profit grouped by state where sum of profit per state > 0. So no deficit states should be there.

The data I am working on looks like this:

[image: 1]

I tried various different code to achieve that, none of them worked for me. Some of them were close to what I needed some of them were not even close. My most recent one looks like this:

```
select state, sum_of_profit, sum_of_profit/sum(sum_of_profit) as perc
from        (select state, sum(profit) as sum_of_profit 
            from superstore
            group by state
            having sum(profit) >= 0 
            ) as temp
group by state, sum_of_profit
order by sum_of_profit desc
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

To display running percentage of each *sum of profit*, then we have to group by `sum_of_profit` only

```
select sum_of_profit, sum_of_profit/sum(sum_of_profit) as perc
from ( 
      select state, sum(profit) as sum_of_profit 
      from superstore
      group by state
      having sum(profit) >= 0 
) as temp
group by sum_of_profit
order by sum_of_profit desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a result of you query I get all rows filled with running perc equal to 1. Why is that?

Comment: Ok .. Can you edit your question and share the expected output from the simple data that you have shared ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select state,city,sum_of_profit,Total,(
                case when sum_of_profit=0 then 1 else sum_of_profit end
                /
                case when Total=0 then 1 else Total end
            ) *100 perc 
from (
    select *,
             sum(profit) over(partition by state ) as sum_of_profit,
             sum(profit) over(order by (select 0) )  Total 
             ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by state order by state) as rw
    from superstore
)a
where a.rw=1
```

Base Data:

```
create table superstore( state varchar(100),city varchar(100),Profit float)
insert into superstore(state,city,Profit) values
('H','K', 41.91),('H','K',219.58  ),('l','c',6.87),('f','f',383.03)
,('f','f',2.52),('l','c',14.17),('l','c',1.97),('l','c',90.72),('l','c',5.78),('l','c',34.47)
```